# How to change style for nodes in NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to figure out how to change the style for group nodes in NSOutlineView.
With setSelectionHighlightStyle I can change the whole list style. But I want to change only the style for group nodes.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I ran into a similar problem, the method @Benedict mentions was never triggered for me. This is because [NSOutlineView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/) has a separate method:

```
- (void) outlineView:(NSOutlineView*)aTableView
     willDisplayCell:(id)aCell
      forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn*)aTableColumn
                item:(id)item;
```

See the documentation for the [NSOutlineViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/). (This formal protocol is new in 10.6 — in previous versions of OS X, the methods were implemented as a category on NSObject.)

Answer (score 3):

`NSOutlineView` is a subclass of `NSTableView`. Implement the [`tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:) in the `NSOutlineView` delegate.

In the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` implement something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    if ([aTableView isGroupRow: rowIndex]) {
        //modify aCell
    }


}
```